# upgrade from 11.10 to 12.10 directly without upgrading to12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/how-do-i-upgrade-straight-from-a-very-old-release-to-the-latest-one)

Can I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.10 directly without upgrading to the 12.04 LTS version? Or is it a compulsion to upgrade to 12.04?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you would want to do that?

Comment: 12.10 does not exist at this time